# JSON (field starting with @) deserialization in Angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

My scenario is really simple. I'm trying to deserialize a JSON inside an Angular2 application. The problem is that in the JSON there is a field that starts with @.

Example:

```
  {
    "@type": ".StringField",
    "name": "description",
    "type": "String",
    "value": "A"
  }
```

So my question is, how do I write a class in Typescript with a field @type? Is there any way to do it in a neat way? I can't figure out a solution.

@Günter Zöchbauer

Consider the following code:

```
  getCustomerProfile(): Observable<CustomerMetaModel> {
    return this.http.get('/customer/metaModel')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response): string {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }
```

I'm not doing the parsing by myself, but I let the function `getCustomerProfile()` do all the job. How do I manage this situation?

Comment: What does the class property need to have the same name?

Comment: Why dont you replace '@type' with 'type' from your json using string operations and continue ur operations with the new json(string you got after replacement)

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, the name does not need to be the same.

Comment: @Amarnath R Shenoy this sounds like a good workaround, but it's not clean imho. I would like to find an Angular2 library that manages this stuff itself :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyClass {
  String xtype;
  String name;
  String type;
  String value;
  constructor(json:any) {
    this.xtype = json['@type'];
    this.name = json.name;
    this.type = json.type;
    this.value = json.value;
  }
}
```

```
var myClass = new MyClass(json);
```

Comment: My doubt is what will happen if you get an object that contains an array of MyClass, you have to do a .map to resolve that array?, just asking btw

Comment: Yes, `map()` would do it

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I added some other info in the question.

Comment: I would need to know what the JSON is exactly you get. Is it a single object like the one in your question or is it an array of such object or is it somehow nested deeper in the JSON?

Comment: In what form do you want to get the data? You don't seem to deserialize anything

Comment: My bad. In the extractData function I was using json() function. I replaced this with a new operator and it worked with your solution! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear :) Thanks for the feedback.